# How to get the extension of Files of resources?

Tags: android, android-drawable

In android, I need to load a set of images from res/drawable directory

I use the following code:

```
Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
        List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            String name = field.getName();
            if (name.startsWith("img")) {
                Picture picture = new Picture(name);
                pictures.add(picture);
            }
        }
```

Among all files in 'drawable', it finds all files starting as a string 'img'.
For this code to work correctly, I have to manually change the names of image files by myself.
If I can get the extension of each resource in drawable (such as jpg, png, etc.), I don't need to change the file name like this.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I appreciate your help, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question.

I moved all the image files into "asset/imgs"
and use the following code to load them

```
List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String[] images = assetManager.list("imgs");
            for (String name : images) {
                Picture picture = new Picture(name);
                pictures.add(picture);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // you can print error or log.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```